# TableViewのCellが正しく表示されない

Tags: swift, swift4, uitableview

以下のサイトを参考にしてプロジェクトを作成しました。
http://an.hatenablog.jp/entry/2015/10/04/015712

cellのIdentifierは"InputTextCell"とし、LabelとTextFieldはAutoLayoutで位置を調整しました。
実行するとTableviewと空のcellが表示されるだけでLabelとTextFieldは表示されません。
何が問題でしょうか。

//viewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, InputTextTableCellDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: InputTextTableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InputTextCell", for: indexPath) as! InputTextTableCell
        // delegate設定
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    // MARK: - UITableViewDelegate
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return InputTextTableCell.height()
    }

    // 追加
    // MARK: - InputTextTableCellDelegate
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(cell: InputTextTableCell, value: NSString) -> () {
        let path = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: cell.convert(cell.bounds.origin, to: tableView))
    NSLog("row = %d, value = %@", path!.row, value)
    }

}
```

//InputTextTableCell.swift

```
import UIKit

// 追加
protocol InputTextTableCellDelegate {
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(cell: InputTextTableCell, value: NSString) -> ()
}

class InputTextTableCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {
    var delegate: InputTextTableCellDelegate! = nil

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    static func height() -> CGFloat {
        return 75.0
    }

    // MARK: - UITextFieldDelegate
    internal func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    // 追加
    internal func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        self.delegate.textFieldDidEndEditing(cell: self, value: textField.text! as NSString)
    }

}
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: UITableViewのdataSourceは設定されているのでしょうか？

Comment: ずいぶん古いコードを参考にされたようで、Swift 2の時代のものである上に必要なステップが明記されていない部分もありますね。一つの問題を解決しても他にあれこれ問題が出てきそうですが、あなたのコードと記述された症状から判断して、nakano531 さんが指摘されたように、参考記事の「TableViewのdelegateとdatasourceはViewControllerに繋ぎます」が正しく出来ていないように思われます。記事ではコードで`delegate`や`dataSource`を設定していないので、Interface Builder上でoutletとして接続してやる必要がありますが、この接続はされたでしょうか? また記事には全く記載されていませんが、あなたのカスタムセルのCustom Classを正しく`InputTextTableCell`にしてやる必要があります。こちらの設定は行われたでしょうか?

Comment: nakano531さん、OOPerさん　ご指摘の通り、StoryBoard上でTableViewDelegateとDataSourceを設定していないのが問題だったようです。無事解決できました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @sayaka さん、「Cellが正しく表示されない」については、無事に解決できたようで、良かったです。できたら時間をとって、ご自身で回答を投稿してみてください。また(自己回答を承認するには一定時間を待たないといけませんが)回答の承認もお願いします。引用された記事は検索の仕方によっては結果のトップに来るのですが、いろいろな手順(著者には丸分かりだったのでしょうが)が省略されており、初学者に優しい記事とは言えません。承認された回答があることで、同じことで悩んでおられる方がこのスレッドを見つけやすくなります。